# Is my Corei7 Running too hot?

Tags: intel-core-i7

I purched a gaming comupter from avatar [This one](http://avatargamingpc.com/gaming-desktop/amddesktop/fx8379.html)

It randomly started shutting itself off out of nowhere. I checked it's temps using speedfan and temp2 is 127C. Basically it shows a fire icon beside it where the rest are green check mars or blue down arrows. I'm not sure what temp 2 is but I'm assuming it's running way way too hot?

Suggestions?

Comment: 127°C is way too hot. The fire icon might very well be no exaggeration. Be very careful with this system, it might be an actual fire hazard. Solve the issue asap.

Comment: A friend of mine says it may not have a head sensor in that spot and that's why it shows it as so hot? I hovered my hands around every possible spot and nothing feels even slightly hot. If it helps, both times it dipped out I was running league of legends and skype.

Comment: Temp2 sounds like an unconnected sensor. It also doesn’t sound like anything related to the CPU at all. Please try HWiNFO32/64 and log a few seconds. Attach this log here.

Comment: http://gyazo.com/024f2629d455970a28c025876c174448 of speedfan. I;ll try what you said.

Comment: http://gyazo.com/22fc6aedc38daa59e14c33402a3cb2a3 Here's a screen shot of what I've got.

Comment: Ah, my bad. I was of course referring to the sensors view (or alternatively, the sensors-only mode) in HWiNFO32/64. It has a logging feature that outputs a CSV file. It includes various measurements like temperatures and voltages.

Answer (score 0):

You have not installed an Intel i7 but an AMD FX-8350. However, apart from that it's too hot anyway. You should change the CPU cooler because it is either broken or not suitable for the performance. Otherwise, you should return the computer because the CPU has already suffered.

Comment: It says intel core 17 inside on it and in my computer properties. So I'm not sure.

Comment: Interesting, Speedfan is reporting an i7 but the link you gave does not offer that as an option. Are you sure it isn't [this one](http://avatargamingpc.com/coenus-i7-4766k-ice.html)? Anyway, IMO the CPU should shut down before that temperature can be reached. Tjmax for that i7 should be around 100C. So either something is defective or Speedfan is inaccurate.